# Mimicking the ubuntu settings wrench button from the command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, bluetooth

When I click on the wrench under the cursor in the image below, then navigate to `bluetooth` the settings page for bluetooth is correctly populated.      My understanding has been that the way to mimic the mouse click from the command line is to type `gnome-control-center bluetooth`.     But when I do that, the GUI says:   `no bluetooth found`.      So the mouse click must be doing something different, i.e., either it's opening a different program or it's opening `gnome-control-center` with some flag.   Could somebody advise please how to correctly mimic from the command-line the mouse-click on the wrench?    Thanks very much for any suggestions.

[image: Ubuntu wrench]

The screenshot below illustrates my problem, for the bluetooth, display and sound screens.    On the left side is what I get from gnome-control-center, on the right is what I get from clicking then wrench.     My apologies for the terrible resolution, but hopefully it will be enough to indicate the problem.

[image: Display screens for Fvwm and Ubuntu]

Answer (score 0):

***OS: Ubuntu 18.04***

This command mimics the one you have asked.. but only drawback is the window is not active..

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "Shell.AppSystem.get_default().lookup_app('gnome-control-center.desktop').activate()"
```

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

---

For fvwm session.. the only option I came across is to install the package `blueman`

```
sudo apt install blueman
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this @PRATAP.    It works perfectly in the `ubuntu` desktop, but I'm actually using `fvwm`.      In that environment, none of the keyboard shortcuts work for some reason.      So I tried simply sourcing the command string you provided, and got this error message: `Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files`       Can you suggest a way to proceed?

Comment: Hi.. What is your 0S and how to install fvwm?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 18.04. fvwm is pretty easy to install: ` sudo apt -y install  fvwm`       Once you've installed it, when you restart and get back to the login page, there will be a drop-down menu giving you the option of choosing `fvwm` or `ubuntu` etc.    This is a pretty good guide:  https://zensites.net/fvwm/guide/index.html

Comment: Hi thanks for info.. Seems it out of my knowledge.. I tried it.. I installed and saw if I can.. But no. I Suggest you to edit your Q and include the info that u want to bring settings dialogue from fvwm. Thanks

Comment: I've added screenshots displaying the displays I get on the left, and what I should get on the right.    Image quality is terrible, but hopefully it will give you the idea.    Thanks so much for your help and patience!!

Comment: Hi.. Left side pics  r fvwm sessions?? I can't reproduce left side pics.. Bcoz when I choose settings it's empty..

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but not certain) that I had to apt install `gnome-control-center` by hand.    But now I have it, the command that generated, for example the bluetooth screen was `sudo env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center bluetooth`

Comment: super.. write the answer.. and accept it after a cooling period of 48hrs..